# Rich visual representation of estimators in Scikit Learn - getting text and not diagram

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the new pipeline visualisation feature in scikit-learn. I am getting the output as the text and not pipeline visualisation diagram in jupyter book or google collab.  I am expecting the diagram as shown in Scikit-Learn documentation.

Please suggest

````
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

TitanicDataset=sns.load_dataset("titanic")
##print(tips.info())
##print(tips.head())
X=TitanicDataset[["sex","age","fare","embarked","who","pclass"]].copy()
y=TitanicDataset[["survived"]].copy()
print(X.info())

numeric_independent_variables= ['fare', 'age', 'pclass']
categorical_independent_variables=["who","embarked","sex"]

numeric_pipeline=Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),('scaler', StandardScaler())])
categorical_pipeline= Pipeline([('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
                                ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

consolidated_pipeline=ColumnTransformer([('num', numeric_pipeline, numeric_independent_variables),
        ('cat', categorical_pipeline, categorical_independent_variables)])

clf = Pipeline(steps=[('consolidated_pipeline', consolidated_pipeline),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])


from sklearn import set_config
set_config(display='diagram')
print(clf)```
````

*Output*

```
Pipeline(steps=[('consolidated_pipeline',
                     ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('num',
                                                      Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',
                                                                       SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
                                                                      ('scaler',
                                                                       StandardScaler())]),
                                                      ['fare', 'age', 'pclass']),
                                                     ('cat',
                                                      Pipeline(steps=[('imputer',
                                                                       SimpleImputer(fill_value='missing',
                                                                                     strategy='constant')),
                                                                      ('onehot',
                                                                       OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))]),
                                                      ['who', 'embarked',
                                                       'sex'])])),
                    ('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use print. Print will always use the object's `__repr__`. Instead use `display` from `IPython.display`, or just end the cell of the notebook with `clf` (not `print(clf)`).